# Why do I need kubernetes Ingress for custom domain?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I deployed my app using kubernetes and now Id like to add custom domain to the app. I am using [this](https://hackernoon.com/expose-your-kubernetes-service-from-your-own-custom-domains-cc8a1d965fc) tutorial and it uses ingress to set the custom domain.
I noticed that the app load balancer has an ip. Why shouldn't I use that ip? What is the reason I need ingress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expose your app, you could just as easily use a service of type `NodePort` instead of an Ingress. You could also use the type `LoadBalancer`. `LoadBalancer` is a superset of `NodePort` and assigns a fixed ip. With the type `LoadBalancer` you could assign a domain to this fixed IP. How to do this depends on where you have registered your domain.

To answer your questions:

- You do not need an Ingress you could use a `NodePort` service or
  `LoadBalander` service.
- To assign a domain to your app, you do not
  need an Ingress, you could use a `LoadBalancer` service
- In any case,
  you could just use the ip, but as already pointed out, a domain is
  more convenient.

If you just want to try out your app, you could just use the IP. A domain can be assigned later.

Here is a official kubernetes tutorial on how to expose an app: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/

Comment: Why not cname the load balancer ip in the DNS?

Comment: Which DNS do you mean?

Comment: I have the IP of the load balancer, so I can config the DNS of the domain to transform to that IP (or is it A record? I am not familiar with DNS)

Comment: Yes, of course you can do that. You need to set the A-Record to the IP.

Comment: So why do I need to use Ingress? Why it is better then A-Record for that ip?

Comment: You do not need an ingress, you can alternatively use a loadbalancer service to have a fixed IP. Either way, if you want your app reachable via your domain, you need an A-Record for that domain to the provided IP. The IP is provided by the ingress or the loadbalancer service.

Answer (score 1):

Using domains over IPs has it's obvious advantages of not having to memorize 158.21.72.879 instead of mydomain.com.

Next, using mydomain.com, you can change your IP as many times as you like without having to change your calls to mydomain.com.

`Ingress` comes in different flavors, is highly configurable, allows for traffic redirection using kubernetes service names and some of them even have their own stats page so you can monitor your requests.

Furthermore, if you are using gcloud or the like, the `LoadBalancer` IP could change (unless confiugred otherwise), assigning you any available IP from your IP pool.

The real question is - why NOT use an `Ingress`?

Comment: Why not cname the load balancer ip in the DNS?